# Notation for multi-variate functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, math-history

I have a question regarding the syntax for multivariate functions and corresponding definitions.  My understanding so far is a function accepts a single argument and this can (should?) be a multi-argument list passed as an ordered tuple.

If:

$f: X \rightarrow Y_0 \times Y_1$

$g: Y_0 \times Y_1 \rightarrow Z$

and an ordered tuple is the result of $f$ and an argument to $g$.

Commonly defined:

$(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$

Should this definition really be:

$(g \circ f)x = gfx$

omitting the parenthesis because the result of $f$ is an ordered tuple?  I.e. already is enclosed in parenthesis.

Confusing the matter more, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) says that a

> function of n variables is a function whose domain is a set of n-tuples

and says for a function:

$f : X_1 \times ... \times X_n \rightarrow Y$

> When using function notation, one usually omits the parentheses surrounding tuples,

So when writing the form $f((x_1, ..., x_n))$, the parenthesis is omitted and instead we write $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$.

I'm a bit confused and could use guidance.  For example, I see Wiki define $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and am asking myself, does this definition work with multi-variate functions.  Again, I would expect this definition to be $(f + g)x = fx + gx$ for a multi-variate argument.  I recall seeing some older mathematics literature and saw use with parenthesis omitted.  For this reason, I'm expanding to math-history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses for an element of a product space do not have the semantics of the parenthesis for evaluation of a function.  The way you are writing expressions suggests you interpret
$$  f(x)  $$
as "$f$" and "$(x)$", where the mere mention of $f$ means to use it for evaluation and the parenthesized expression is a $1$-tuple.  This is not the semantics of those uses of those symbols.  $f$ is the name/label of a function, the parentheses have the semantics of evaluation -- in particular, evaluate the function named prior to the parentheses on the input enclosed in the parentheses.

The expression $fx$ is not normally a valid sentence since it is two adjacent nouns.  If you intend to evaluate $f$ at $x$, parentheses are needed.

Consequently, in
$$  f((x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n))  $$
the outer parentheses have the semantics of function evaluation and the inner parentheses have the semantics of $n$-tuple aggregation.  It is a lexicographical hack (to improve legibility) to combine the doubled open parentheses into a single open parenthesis and the doubled close parentheses into a single close parenthesis.  This combination is merely one of presentation in textual form, it represents the doubled form, with both evaluation and aggregation parentheses.

Comment: I recall seeing $fx$ used in both Alonzo Church Formal Mathematics and Intro to the Lambda Calculus as a form.  Nevertheless, your explanation seems to agree with Wiki.  Is a univariate function $f((x))$ and lexicographically hacked to be $f(x)$?  If a multi-variate function is $f((x_1, x_2, ..., x_n))$, is the function $f((x_1, x_2, ..., x_n), (y_1, y_2, ..., y_n))$ possible?  Does this function change the meaning of multi-variate?

Comment: @Nick : The question is tagged "multivariable calculus"; consequently, the typographical conventions of Alonzo Church Formal Mathematics and Intro to the Lambda Calculus do not apply.  A univariate function evaluation is "$f(x)$" because there is no benefit in making an element of the domain into a $1$-tuple.  (Once you start tupling elements, at what nesting depth do you stop and how much pointless parenthesis gymnastics do you have to add to your syntax?)  Certainly, your final example of $f : \Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^n$ is possible, but why not just mash these together into a $2n$-tuple?

Comment: Understood.  Does $((x_1,x_2,...,x_n),(y_1,y_2,...,y_n))$ become $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n, y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ by an ordered pair identity?  I'm not sure

Comment: @Nick : Labelling the source spaces as $x_i \in X_i$ and $y_i \in Y_i$, there is a straightforward identity: $(X_1 \times \cdots X_n) \times (Y_1 \times \cdots \times Y_n) = X_1 \times \cdots X_n \times Y_1 \times \cdots \times Y_n$.  You should have no trouble showing inclusion in each direction.  In fact, you should have no trouble showing Cartesian product is associative.

Comment: I think I understand.  Finally, I think $f((x_1,x_2,...,x_n), (y_1,y_2,...,y_n))$ would be a form of a lexicographical hack since functions accept a single argument, which may be a ordered tuple.  Therefore, it is really represented by $f(((x_1,x_2,...,x_n), (y_1,y_2,...,y_n)))$, which a single tuple is passed as the only argument.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Nick : I can make sense of what you have written.  I worry that you are descending into the useless tarpit of over-emphasizing the syntax of tuples -- thinking that the tuple parentheses are representing deep mathematics when they are not.  Also, not all functions accept a single argument.  The addition function takes two arguments, not a tuple of two elements.  This distinction is largely syntax instead of semantics so belaboring it accomplishes little.